# Which oauth or openid-connect I need to choose in order to build a public sdk?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am going to build an SDK for developers to access my backend restful resources. 
For example, I defined below restful apis:

```
get     GET  /changes/changeId  
list    GET  /changes   
getStartPageToken   GET  /changes/startPageToken
```

I need to secure my apis and I come across openid-connect, auth1 and auth2 but I am not sure which one I need to use. As far as I know, auth2 is more used to third-party authentication like login as `google`, `facebook` account etc. Is this right?

In some other public APIs design, a developer need to register a developer account and get an app key and secret. They can use the key and secret to use their APIs. Which type of this authentication is it?

Which one among them is more appropriate for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

[OAuth 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) has been obsolete by [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). So you can remove OAuth 1.0 from your inventory.

Now the different between OAuth 2.0 and [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) is on their purpose. OAuth 2.0 is a framework built for authorization. OpenID Connect is built on top of OAuth 2.0 (extending its ability) and provides authorization as well as authentication (authentication is built on [id token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)).

Now, these protocols enable you to complete a protocol flow and obtain tokens from an authorization server (sometime called an identity provider or an identity server). Unlike you maintaining users per application, user registry is maintained by authorization serve which can be shared between several applications. Also, authorization server will issue and maintain tokens. Also it will provide token validation mechanisms to be used by token consumers (ex:- [OAuth 2.0 Token introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662)).

**As far as I know, auth2 is more used to third-party authentication**

Not necessarily. As highlighted above, this approach enable you to centralised user account maintenance. And provide ways to obtain tokens against users for internal applications as well. Allowing third-party to authenticate comes as a bonus.

**In some other public APIs design, a developer need to register a developer account and get an app key and secret. They can use the key and secret to use their APIs.**

OAuth 2.0 (OpenID Connect) also require you to register you application at authorization server. But unlike app key, secret based approach (or API key based approach), what OAuth 2.0 provide you is the ability to automate token obtaining and token refreshing process. This is done by following a defined flow (ex:- [Authorization code flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)). Tokens having shorter life time and ability to revoke them benefit security wise as well.

**Which one among them is more appropriate for my use case?**

I prefer you to go with either OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect. With them, you can protect your APIs with access tokens. Users of your SDK should will send the access token as defined in [Bearer Token Usage](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)

Now what to choose between OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect ?

Well it depends what client end required from SDK. If client applications need to identify the end user and authenticate them, then you should choose OpenID Connect. But if client application only need to consume API, then you can use OAuth 2.0. Either way, your API must be called with a valid access token. And your API should validate access token before granting access.